# Insert lines from an input file every n lines in awk

Tags: awk, sed, cat, split

With input files A and B as such:

File A

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

File B

```
10 10 10
20 20 20
30 30 30
40 40 40
50 50 50
60 60 60 
70 70 70
```

I would like to insert one line of file A every 3 lines of file B, starting with the first line being the first line of file A so that the output would like so:

```
1 1 1
10 10 10
20 20 20
30 30 30
2 2 2
40 40 40
50 50 50
60 60 60 
3 3 3 
70 70 70
```

My original attempt at this involved creating separate files for every three lines, but my dataset is extremely large so I'm interested in saving hard drive space.

Comment: Could you please post what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to use awk, paste could work:

```
$ paste -d '\n' <fileB fileA - - - | tr -s '\n' >fileC
```

The `tr` part isn't strictly necessary, so you can remove it if you don't mind extra newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good case for `getline`:

```
awk '(NR-1)%3 == 0 {getline line < "FileA"; print line} 1' FileB
1 1 1
10 10 10
20 20 20
30 30 30
2 2 2
40 40 40
50 50 50
60 60 60 
3 3 3
70 70 70
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed’s `R` command:

```
sed -e $'R fileb\nR fileb\nR fileb' filea > output
```